# Oracle SQL AS replacement?

Tags: sql, oracle

Through some research I've come to realize that Oracle SQL does not support AS and thus, my statement below results in "missing keyword"

```
SELECT IP.Company, IP.Copay, P1.Num_Patients
FROM Insurance_Plan IP
JOIN Patient P
    ON IP.Plan_Name = P.Plan_Name
JOIN
    (SELECT Plan_Name, COUNT(*) AS Num_Patients
    FROM Patient
    GROUP BY Plan_Name) AS P1
    ON P.Plan_Name = N.Plan_Name
GROUP BY IP.Company, IP.Copay, P1.Num_Patients
HAVING P1.Num_Patients =
    (SELECT MAX(Num_Patients) FROM
        (SELECT Plan_Name, COUNT(Patient_ID) AS Num_Patients
        FROM Patient
        GROUP BY Pan_Name) P2);
```

Where I run in to trouble is on line 8 where I have "AS P1" and I cannot for the life of me figure out what it is I need to correct to get this to run. Appreciate the help!

Comment: just remove the AS - the literal will become the alias.

Comment: Sometimes the answers are right in front of your face... Thank you!

Comment: FYI `AS` is optional in T-SQL (Microsoft SQL Server). I don't know about other platforms but I am certainly in the habit of not using `AS`

Comment: @NewPythonUser - In Oracle, table/inline view aliases may not be preceded by a keyword (such as `AS`). **Column** aliases MAY be preceded by the keyword `AS`, which is **optional**. I personally always use `AS` for column aliases, I believe this way queries are easier to read.